# Retain long Docker tags in local registry after pushing to remote?

Tags: docker

To push a Docker image from my local machine to a remote repository (on Amazon's ECR, in my case), I understand that it has to be tagged with the repo hostname so Docker knows where to push it. The typical sequence is like

```
    $ docker tag myimage:v1 400000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:v1
    $ docker push 400000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:v1
```

When the push is done, I have two names for the image in my machine's local registry -- the original short "generic" one and the long repo-specific one.

Is there any value in retaining those long names in my local registry, or is it reasonable to just delete them after the push? I understand that I'm not saving any real disk space by removing the long name (since the image is still referred to by the short one), but in the interest of removing clutter I'd prefer not to keep them unless there's a good reason. I can always use the ECR console or other tools to review the images that are in the remote repository.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using manual `docker` commands, I might suggest keeping only the long ECR-based name.  Beyond having a much shorter name to type, there's no particular benefit to having two names for the same image, and it does get in the way of some things like image cleanup.

Even if you're using plain Docker commands, you can set a shell variable to the ECR repository name to save some typing:

```sh
ECR=400000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
docker build -t "$ECR/myimage:20210708" .
docker push "$ECR/myimage:20210708"
```

If you're using a tool like Docker Compose, you can write out the full repository name in the `docker-compose.yml`, but having done that, you only need to do it once; there's no particular need for the short name.

In a Kubernetes context, if you're using [Helm](https://helm.sh) for deployment, it turns out to be very useful to split "repository", "image", and "tag" into three separate values.  This is doubly true since the Docker Hub rate limiting went into place, since it lets you set the repository to a local mirror.

```yaml
image: {{ .Values.repository }}/{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}
```

```yaml
repository: docker-mirror.example.com # chart default: docker.io
image: my/image
tag: '20210708'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the unexpected-but-reasonable advice! I'll have to think about using only long names, as much of the work is done locally and by folks who don't even have access to the AWS resources. Perhaps in those situations we could just set a global prefix (like your $ECR) that would be some non-Amazon-specific string when working outside the ECR context. Thanks again!